# how to write an xpath that returns the result of function b if function a returns empty

Tags: xpath

I have two `xpath` functions that I want to combine

**a - return the subdomain string if it's not "www"**

```
replace(substring-before(replace(//url,"(https?://)",""),"."),"www","")
```

**b - return the subfolder name**

```
substring-before(replace(//url,"(https?://[^/]+/)",""),"/")
```

Is it possible to have an xpath that returns b if a is empty, otherwise it returns a?

Example:

```
http://aaaa.something.com/bbbb should return "aaaa"
http://www.something.com/bbbb should return "bbbb"
```

Comment: Can you give an example and what you are looking for?

Comment: done, you can see it now on the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging into @Michael's suggestion, I found the answer:

```
(a, b)[string-length() > 0][1]
```

which in my example translates into:

```
(replace(substring-before(replace(//url,"(https?://)",""),"."),"www",""), replace(replace(//url,"(https?://[^/]+[/])",""),"[/+].*",""))[string-length() > 0][1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I assumed by "empty" you meant "empty sequence". In the specs we're very careful to avoid talking about an "empty string", we always call it a "zero-length string" to avoid this misunderstanding. But of course I should have spotted that neither of your function calls is likely to return an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have an xpath that returns b if a is empty,
>   otherwise it returns a?

The usual XPath 2.0 idiom for that is

```
(a, b)[1]
```

(Efficiency here depends on piped evaluation, but I think you can assume that any half-decent processor when given `X[1]` will avoid evaluating items in X beyond the first).

Comment: `(replace(substring-before(replace(//url,"(https?://)",""),"."),"www",""), substring-before(replace(//url,"(https?://[^/]+/)",""),"/"))[1]`

when i test it with the second example it returns empty :/